# How to use .onFailure in scala Future?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, error-handling, future, throwable

My scenario is that suppouse for now I have a function `abc()` which has a return type of `Future[Unit]`(or it can also have a return type ) , now someone has given me a task that if this `abc` function failes it just print a logger statement and that's it  , it should not fail the parent function inside which it is wrapped around , and he also recommended me to use `Future.onFailure` . Now what I have tried is

```
abc(some , random ,code ).onFailure(e=>{
    logger.debug("I don't want to through error : ${e}")
})
```

But intellij is showing me this

[image]

I am not able to understand what does this error means ? What should be way out for this ? And if possible please explain more about onFaiure in Futures with examples

Thanks in advance

Comment: The right syntax would be `abc(...).onError { case ex: Throwable => ... }` so it is a partial function instead of a total one. In any case, that won't recover the `Future` thus whatever depends on it will still keep failing which seems is not what you want.

Comment: To recover you should use `recover` or `recoverWith`. And pass the returned `Future` instead of the original one. `onSuccess`, `onFailure` and `onComplete` are fire-and-forget type of calls which don't return recovered values.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I want to use onFailure specifically and was not able to understand this partial function part , so can you suggest any doc around it ?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok My aim is same I don't want `abc()` function to interfere in operations of its parent functions , it should be like this that if `abc()` executes that's fine but if not then it should just end up with a message

Comment: onFailure receives a "Partial" function while you are passing a function to it. `abc(...).onFailure { case myThrowable: ThrowableTypeToCatch => yourLogic() }` would work.

Comment: I suggest reading [what is a `Future`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) and [what is a partial function](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala). It's rather obvious that you jumped into some specific task without covering the basics.